# KVM VMs and virtual network, how to assign external IP addresses?

Tags: linux, networking, redhat, kvm-virtualization, bridge

So, my question is: there is a remote server on Red-Hat with an external IP-address, eth0: inet addr: 87.112.140.53 Bcast: 87.112.140.255 Mask: 255.255.252.0, and is a virtual interface, which raises the kvm - virbr0: inet addr: 192.168.122.1 Bcast: 192.168.122.255

And I made two virtual machines that with that virbr0 received addresses at the interface via DHCP.

Problem: how to assign my VMs two external IP address from the network 87.112.140.0?

Answer (score 3):

192.168.122.x are the default NAT networks set up by libvirt. If you want the VMs to be in the same network as the host, you need to set up a bridged network instead.
take a look here: http://www.linux-kvm.com/content/using-bridged-networking-virt-manager